Why do animals excrete organic nitrogen compounds instead of N2 gas?
Protein metabolism produces ammonia, which needs to be disposed of; but oxidation of ammonia into water and dinitrogen produces energy, while creating urea or uric acid consumes energy, and excreting it expands water. So, it seems like there would be some small advantage to animals exhaling N2 instead of excreting nitrogen in liquid or solid form. Nevertheless, no animal does so, and as far as I know, the only organisms that do are denitrifying bacteria and archaea.
So, is there a good reason why animals shouldn't produce nitrogen gas? bother with that, rather than just exhaling nitrogen gas? Or is it just a matter of "evolution isn't directed"--a random quirk that the ancestors of animals didn't happen to develop ammonia-oxidizing pathways?
There are a few reasons I can think of, or that have been suggested to me, that nitrogen production might actually be deleterious, but I can't find references to back up any of them:

Nitrogen has low solubility, and bubbles in blood or tissues are bad. Would this actually be a limiting factor?
The pathways that oxidize ammonia in microbes might interfere with other parts of animalian metabolism. I have absolutely no idea how plausible this is.
The energy gain from oxidizing ammonia may be too small to justify the cost of maintaining metabolic machinery for it.

So, is there any actual science on this?

Please everyone remember to answer in the answer box and not the comments.

If the answer is helpful and adequately explains why uric acid is the end product of the elimination of ammonia in animals, then it's customary (and the polite thing to do) to accept it.

for any evolution question a good rule of thumb is to ask yourself what benefit would this have? for instance exhaling N2 is not a benfit its one more gas you have to get rid of that is competeing for space with the oxygen you want to inhale.

In an answer to a previous evolutionary ”why“ question I devoted a paragraph to the general problem with questions of the type “Why has such and such not evolved, it would obviously be advantageous?”. Two points I made were:

“It would be too difficult, costly or would have disadvantageous consequences”

and/or

“The assumption that it would convey a selective advantage… is incorrect.”

In the present case both apply. A mechanism that evolved for elimination of ammonia in a particular species would be fixed if it did just that. Not if it also might do something else for which the organism already has highly evolved and sophisticated machinery†. And it is worth my repeating that the idea that energy costs are a limiting factory in the evolution of multicellular organisms is false. We are not bacteria competing for a limited supply of nutrients so we can procreate more rapidly. We have energy to “waste” (and long gestation periods).
Second, the fact that so few organisms can oxidize ammonia to nitrogen implies that this is a multistep conversion with chemical difficulties that can only be overcome in certain environmental niches. In contrast, the urea cycle is built up largely from pre-existing part reactions that had already evolved in a wide range of bacteria (see, e.g. this Bioessay review). The key reaction that produces carbamoyl phosphate from ammonia and bicarbonate has a counterpart in pyrimidine synthesis, and although there are separate enzymes for these processes in eukaryotes (pyrimidine synthesis uses glutamine, rather than ammonia) a single bifunctional enzyme is found in bacteria (see the Wikipedia entry for carbamoyl phosphate synthetase).
† I have not dealt with possible problems mentioned by the poster regarding the generation of nitrogen gas in the blood as these are only secondary to my main points, which would exclude the idea from the start.

Since animals get most of their nitrogen intake through protein / amino acids, breaking that down to molecular nitrogen is a multi-step process. Indeed that breakdown process can provide energy all the way down to the molecular components.
However, in a multi-step process, if you have limited resources, it is generally speaking an advantage to focus all your resources on the most efficient step. This way you can convert more energy than if say you'd put only half of your resources on the most efficient step and the other half in a less efficient step.
If we are just looking at one of the most basic amino acids, Glutamic acid, we have a Gibbs free energy of formation of -476 kJ/mol (chemeo.com). Glutamate can be broken down in a single biochemical reaction to ammonia and a carbohydrate. Ammonia has a Gibbs free energy of formation of -16 kJ/mol, which indicates that the first degradation step provides much more energy than the subsequent steps. Because of this, organisms that get nitrogen in the form of amino acids have an energy-efficiency advantage if they only do the breakdown until ammonia and not all the way to molecular nitrogen.
Of course that leaves an ecological niche for other organisms to make use of the wasted ammonia and convert the remaining energy there. Actually this is also a multi-step process, which is mostly done by different microbial species (ammonia oxidizer, nitrifyers, and denitrifyers). This has been studied from the perspective of microbial division of labor.
